# Elasticsearch Spark, how to query multiple times?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, elasticsearch-hadoop

I'm on jupyter notebook.

I'd like to use query dsl to prepare initial Dataframe.

I use `conf.set("es.query", dsl_query)` for that. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html#_querying)

But then, I want to apply different query to prepare another Dataframe, and I can't find a way to apply a new dsl_query without creating new `SparkContext`

But I didn't find a way to recreate a `SparkContext` inside jupyter environment either.

I want to run analysis using QueryDSL-1 as baseline
then run another anlysis using QueryDSL-2 as another baseline

Is there a way of doing this without creating two notebook?

Comment: you don't need to define the query in your spark conf...

Comment: you can specify the es.query as an option to your DataFrameReader i.e `spark.read.option("es.query", dsl_query).option("...", "...")` ...

Comment: yes it works, can you make it as an answer, so i can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just need to specify the `es.query` as an option to your `DataFrameReader` i.e :

```
spark.read.option("es.query", dsl_query).option("...", "...")
```